# primeng p-fileUpload does not send the multipart file in weblogic 12c

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c, primeng

I have a spring boot application with a controller to upload a file from primeng using the p-fileUpload.  When I run the spring boot service in STS as a Sprint Boot App, everything works fine, but when I deploy the service to weblogic 12c R2 (12.2.1.1) the controller method gets an empty list.

The code is below. What do I need to do to get weblogic to work?

```
        // 3.1.2 Multiple file upload
    // @PostMapping("/api/upload/multi")
//  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/upload/multi/{fein}" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFileMulti(
            @PathVariable Long fein,
            // @RequestParam("extraField") String extraField,
            @RequestPart("uploadFiles") List<MultipartFile> myFiles) {

        log.info("Multiple file upload!");

        // Get file name
        // String uploadedFileName = Arrays.stream(uploadFiles).map(x ->
        // x.getOriginalFilename())
        // .filter(x -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(x)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ,
        // "));
        //
        // if (StringUtils.isEmpty(uploadedFileName)) {
        // return new ResponseEntity("please select a file!", HttpStatus.OK);
        // }

        // Check for empty files.
        for (MultipartFile myFile : myFiles) {
            log.info("Attempting to upload of files=" + myFile.getOriginalFilename());
            if (myFile.isEmpty()) {
                log.error("No file specified!");
                return new ResponseEntity<>("No file specified!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }

        try {

//          saveUploadedFiles( fein, Arrays.asList(myFiles));
            saveUploadedFiles( fein, myFiles);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully uploaded - file(s).", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form [formGroup]="attachmentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p-panel header="Instructions">
                            <ul class="no-list-style">
                                <li><label>Step 1: Click Browse to find the document(s) you want to upload</label></li>
                                <li><label>Step 2: Click Upload</label></li>
                                <li><label>Step 3: Click Save</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </p-panel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p-fileUpload name="uploadFiles" url={{uploadUrlString}} accept={{acceptString}} maxFileSize="50000000" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)"></p-fileUpload>
                            <!-- <label>File Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value={{selectedAttachment.filName}} formControlName="filename" /> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>File Name</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" value={{selectedAttachment.filName}} formControlName="filename"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Comments</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" value={{selectedAttachment.comments}} formControlName="comments"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-left" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px">Save Attachment</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-left" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px"
                        (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much research, this turned out to be solution for weblogic 12c.  I hope this helps folks.

```
    package com.demo.configuration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.demo.environment.DemoEnvironment;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
        basePackages = { "com.demo.dao.oracle" })
public class OracleConfiguration {

    DemoEnvironment env = new DemoEnvironment();

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.oracle.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.demo.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("DEMO")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:7001");
        String allowedOrigin = this.env.getAllowedOrigin();
        config.addAllowedOrigin(allowedOrigin);
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }   

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

}

pom.xml:

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

application.properties:

spring.http.multipart.enabled=false


Controller:

/**
 * 
 */
package com.demo.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;

import com.demo.entity.Atchmnt;
import com.demo.environment.DemoEnvironment;
import com.demo.service.AttachmentService;
import com.demo.util.Base64Util;

/**
 * @author Denis
 *
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@RestController
public class RestUploadController {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    DemoEnvironment env = new DemoEnvironment();

    @Autowired
    private AttachmentService attachmentService;

    @Autowired
    private MultipartResolver multipartResolver;

    // private String uploadFolder = "c://temp//"; // this needs to be in
    // the application.properties file.
    private String uploadFolder = env.getFilesDirectory();


    // 3.1.2 Multiple file upload
    // @PostMapping("/api/upload/multi")
//  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/upload/multi/{fein}" }, 
                    method = { RequestMethod.POST }, 
                    consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, 
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFileMulti(
            @PathVariable Long fein,
            // @RequestParam("extraField") String extraField,
            @RequestPart("uploadFiles") MultipartFile[] myFiles,
            HttpServletRequest req
            ) {

        log.info("Multiple file upload!");

        // Get file name
        // String uploadedFileName = Arrays.stream(uploadFiles).map(x ->
        // x.getOriginalFilename())
        // .filter(x -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(x)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ,
        // "));
        //
        // if (StringUtils.isEmpty(uploadedFileName)) {
        // return new ResponseEntity("please select a file!", HttpStatus.OK);
        // }

        // Check for empty files.
        for (MultipartFile myFile : myFiles) {
            log.info("Attempting to upload of files=" + myFile.getOriginalFilename());
            if (myFile.isEmpty()) {
                log.error("No file specified!");
                return new ResponseEntity<>("No file specified!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }

        try {

            saveUploadedFiles( fein, Arrays.asList(myFiles));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully uploaded - file(s).", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // save file
    private void saveUploadedFiles(Long fein, List<MultipartFile> files) throws IOException {

        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            log.info("Attempting to upload the requested file.");

            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                continue; // next pls
            }

            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            String folderPath = createFileSystemFolder( uploadFolder + "/" + fein );
            log.info("saving file=" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Path path = Paths.get(folderPath + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
        }
    }

    public String createFileSystemFolder(String folderPath) {
        log.info("createFileSystemFolder(): attempting to create folder=" + folderPath );
        File file = new File(folderPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        } else {
            log.error("createFileSystemFolder(): failed to create the folder.");
        }
        return folderPath + "/";
    }

}
```